# Swift class field of type var Array is converted to immutable NSArray instead of NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, swift, nsmutablearray, nsarray, xcode6

A simple Swift class has a field of type var Array. When the class is adapted to Objective-C the field type is exposed as NSArray (immutable) while it should be NSMutableArray (mutable)

```
class Categoryy: NSObject {

    var items = Array<Item>()

}
```

The Categoryy swift class is adapted to Objective-C in the Xcode-generated header MODULE_NAME-swift.h file as following:

```
SWIFT_CLASS("_TtC8waiterio9Categoryy")
@interface Categoryy : NSObject
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSArray * items;
- (instancetype)init OBJC_DESIGNATED_INITIALIZER;
@end
```

is there a way for the var items : Array field to be converted to a mutable NSMutableArray in Objective-c?

Comment: You aren't able to change the header to NSMutableArray?

Comment: it isn't a feasible solution :( The Xcode-generated header for Swift named MODULE-swift.h is erased and recreated by Xcode each time one of the swift files changes a field or method signature. You can change manually the type of fields from NSArray to NSMutableArray but as soon as you change a swift file's fields or methods' signature all your changes are lost.

Comment: Did you file a radar on this?

Answer (score 6):

That is because `items` property is actually **immutable**.

[As you know](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-XID_150), because of the nature of `struct` based implementation of `Array` in Swift, following code does not affect `cat.items`.

```
let cat = Categoryy()

var _items = cat.items
_items.append(item)
```

Instead, you have to call like this

```
cat.items.append(item)
```

On the other hand, in Objective-C, `[cat.items addObject:item]` is exactly same as following:

```
id _items = [cat items];
[_items addObject:item];
```

That is very similar to non-working Swift code.

Sad to say, Objective-C does not have equivalent property/method calling semantics as `cat.items.append(item)` in Swift.

This is similar to:

```
// Objective-C
CGRect frame = view.frame;
view.frame = CGRectMake(frame.origin.x, 50, frame.size.width, frame.size.height)

// Swift
view.frame.origin.y = 50
```

--

Maybe Apple can implement that as `NSMutableArray`(or private subclass), of course you can request that.
I doubt Apple will do that, because that breaks compile time type safety by Generics.

Anyway, I think, you should implement `Categoryy` like this:

```
class Categoryy: NSObject {
    var items:[Item] = []

    func addItem(item:Item) {
        items.append(item)
    }

    func setItem(item:Item, atIndex:Int) {
        items[atIndex] = item;
    }

    // and so on ..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want an `NSMutableArray`, the easiest way is to just use an `NSMutableArray` in Swift. `Array<T>` doesn't (and couldn't) both behave as (an immutable) `NSArray` and `NSMutableArray` at the same time - right now, what it does behave as is as an immutable `NSArray`. Swift could use a built-in class type that corresponds to `NSMutableArray` the way `Array<T>` corresponds to `NSArray` though.

Another alternative is to use a Swift class wrapping an `NSMutableArray` with `@objc` exposed methods to access the `NSMutableArray`. That also lets you use generics to constrain items to `T`.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you could call `append` in the Swift file using a method, instead of accessing the Swift array directly in Objective-C.

Swift:

```
func addItem(item:Item)
{
    items.append(item)
}
```

Objective-C:

```
[yourSwiftObject addItem:item];
```